# Android OnItemClickListener not firing

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, onitemclicklistener

I recently finished a project using activities and a nav drawer which worked just fine. I decided for a more robust project, I would use fragments instead of new activities. Of course, my code is almost identical, but I can't get the onClick to fire when an item from the navigation drawer is selected. Any help would be wonderful. I'm concerned about drawerNavListView (the left nav drawer)

MainTemplate extends Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_template);

    // drawer creation
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
    drawerNavListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    drawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    navItem = new ArrayList<NavMenuItem>();

    navItem.add(new NavMenuItem("1", false, null));
    navItem.add(new NavMenuItem("2", true, "0"));
    navItem.add(new NavMenuItem("3", false, null));
    navItem.add(new NavMenuItem("4", false, null));
    navItem.add(new NavMenuItem("5", false, null));
    navItem.add(new NavMenuItem("6", false, null));
    navItem.add(new NavMenuItem("7", false, null));

    menuAdapter = new NavMenuAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navItem);
    drawerNavListView.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

    // create the blank fragment
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    MainPageFrag mFrag = new MainPageFrag();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_space, mFrag);
    ft.commit();

    // JSON get class creation for notifications
    new myNotificationTask().execute(); // call class at bottom

    ...

    // listener for clicking of a notification drawer item
    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideOptionsClickListener());

    // listener for selecting a navigation drawer item
    drawerNavListView.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideNavClickListener());

    // getting screen size
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    screenSize = new Point();
    display.getSize(screenSize);
    // setting pixels per minute for device
    ppm = (screenSize.x * 4) / (25 * 60);

    // create handler to call the notification update every 30 seconds
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    ...
}
```

... (same class)

```
private class SlideNavClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    // this is where we inflate the fragment to the screen depending on the
    // selection
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        switch (position) {
        case 0: 

            ScheduleViewFrag sFrag = new ScheduleViewFrag();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_space, sFrag);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
            break;
        case 1: 
            DelayFrag dFrag = new DelayFrag();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(NOTIF_ID, drawerItems.get(position).getId());
            dFrag.setArguments(bundle);

            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_space, dFrag);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
            break;
        default: // add more fragments once implemented here
                break;

        }

        drawerNavListView.setSelection(position);
        mDrawer.closeDrawer(drawerNavListView);

    }
}
```

Comment: do you have buttons in the row of the ListView ?

Comment: the items in the drawer are a linearlayout base with image and textviews

Comment: supposing the LinearLayout is the root of your item row, add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to it and try it again

Comment: no luck unfortunately

Comment: 'onClick to fire when an item from the navigation drawer is selected', can you explain this line a little bit more

Comment: i open the nav drawer and select and item, onItemClick from the code above should get called, at which point the frag is loaded. From all of my debugging attempts, onItemClick is not being called at all.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out the entire problem was within my xml file for the main layout. Apparently, having the linearlayout containing the fragment for the main screen ABOVE the two listviews for the navigation drawers activated the onclick listeners. I originally had it below the two, and for some reason, that caused my issue. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.